# Why does everyone use latin1?

Tags: php, mysql, internationalization, phpmyadmin

Someone just said utf8 has variable length encoding from 1 to 3 bytes.

So why does everyone still use latin1?  If the same thing is stored in utf8 it is also 1 byte, but utf8 has the advantage that it can adapt to a larger character set.

- Is their a hidden reason everyone uses latin1?
- What are the disadvantages of using utf8 vs. latin1?

Comment: I find that a lot of the time people use it because it's the default and they don't bother to change it.

Comment: No, only the first 128 characters are 1 byte in UTF-8, the characters from 128–255 are 2 bytes.

Comment: I can't remember the last time I deliberately used Latin 1.

Comment: Are all latin1 characters in the first 128 character set you mention?

Comment: @David19801: ISO 8859-1 has 256 characters where the first 128 characters are identical to those of US-ASCII. In UTF-8, that’s character set is a superset of ISO 8859-1 (the first 256 characters of the Unicode character set are identical to those of ISO 8859-1), only the first 128 characters (thus the characters of US-ASCII) are encoded using one byte; but the remaining 128 characters of the Unicode character set that are identical to those of ISO 8859-1 (i.e. those from 128–255) are encoded using two bytes.

Comment: @David19801: Most European languages that use Latin1 need characters beyond the first 128 of Latin1.

Comment: what are the characters from 128-255?  are they important/special or everyday used?

Comment: @David19801 '£' is in the extended range and encoded as two bytes using UTF-8 (compared to a single byte when encoded as ISO-8859-1). I'd call that both important, and in everyday use, but then again, I'm British; The French may be more interested in 'ç'; Germans,'ü' etc.

Comment: This looks to me more subjective, and would fit better on programmers.se.

Comment: as per my test the index file size of MyISAM table was compressed by 5% after changing the table encoding from UTF-8 to latin. This may improve the performance to some extend.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ISO 8859-1 is the (at least de facto) default character encoding of multiple standards like [HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.7.1) (at least for textual contents):

> When no explicit charset parameter is provided by the sender, media subtypes of the "text" type are defined to have a default charset value of "ISO-8859-1" when received via HTTP. Data in character sets other than "ISO-8859-1" or its subsets MUST be labeled with an appropriate charset value.

The reason that ISO 8859-1 was chosen is probably as it’s a superset of US-ASCII that is the fundamental character set for internet based technologies. And as the World Wide Web was invented and developed at CERN in Geneva, Switzerland, that might be the reason to choose characters of Western European languages for the 128 remaining characters.

When the Unicode standard was developed, the character set of ISO 8859-1 was used for the base of the Unicode character set (the *Universal Character Set*) so that the first 256 character are identical to those of ISO 8859-1. This was probably done due to the importance of ISO 8859-1 for the Web as it already was the standard character encoding for many technologies.

Now to discuss the advantages of ISO 8859-1 in opposite to UTF-8, we need to look at the underlying character sets and the encoding schemes that are used to encode these characters:

- ISO 8859-1 contains 256 characters where the character point of each character is directly mapped onto its binary representation. So 123<sub>10</sub> is encoded with 01111011<sub>2</sub>.
- UTF-8 uses a prefixed variable length encoding scheme where the prefix indicates the word length. UTF-8 is used to encode the characters of the Universal Character Set and its encoding scheme can encode 1,048,576 characters. The first 128 characters require 1 byte, the characters in 0x80–0x7FF require 2 bytes, the characters in 0x800–0xFFFF require 3 bytes, and the characters in 0x10000–0x1FFFFF require 4 bytes.

So the difference if the range of codeable characters on the one hand and the length of the encoded word on the other hand.

So the choice of the “right” character encoding depends on the needs: If you only need the characters of ISO 8859-1 (or US-ASCII as a subset of it), use ISO 8859-1 as it only requires one byte for each character in opposite to UTF-8 where the characters 128–255 require two bytes. And if you need more or other characters than those in ISO 8859-1, use UTF-8.

Comment: +1 but it bears reiterating that despite this de-facto-standard status, UTF-8 is a fine, widely supported standard and the only viable option if internationalization is an issue. (Not correcting what you said, just annotating)

Answer (score 3):

1) Performance reasons.
With a constant-length, going to the n-th character of a string is easy. With variable length, you have to go through all characters from the beginning of the string to know their length.
The only way to achieve this performance in unicode is through utf-32 (all characters are 4 bytes). But it takes more memory.

2) All characters with diacritics (accents) in Latin-1 are in the 128-255 range of latin-1, and therefore are encoded with more than one character in utf-8.

3) A lot of programmer don't know how to use unicode

Comment: point 3) What do you mean here?  What special skills are required that latin1 does not use?

Comment: For example knowing that you need to set up proper conneection encodingig between PHP and MySQL, otherwise you store and retrieve trash.

Comment: There are a fair few things to know about unicode and character sets in general, this is a good starting point: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 1):

This could be a "reason"

```
Everyone uses latin1 because everyone else is too..
```

Its really annoying mixing different them, so you go with what the rest goes with

(i'm not saying it's a *good* reason, but I think it's one some people use)